# How can I change the type of output?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

My sample query is:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(CASE WHEN tb.[CashStatus] = 0 AND tb.[CashPayMethod] = 0  THEN tb.[CashPayPrice] ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalCashPrice],
    SUM(CASE WHEN tb.[CashStatus] = 0 AND tb.[CashPayMethod] = 10 THEN tb.[CashPayPrice] ELSE 0 END) AS [TotalPOSPrice]
FROM
    mytable tb
```

The result is:

```
TotalCashPrice | TotalPOsPrice
---------------+----------------
 41,000,000    |    12,000,000
```

I want to change it to:

```
Value            | Name
-----------------+--------------------
  41,000,000     | TotalCashPrice
  12,000,000     | TotalPOSPrice
```

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `GROUP BY` and move the `CASE` expression to the column being aggregated:

```
SELECT (CASE WHEN tb.CashPayMethod = 0 THEN 'TotalCashPrice'
             WHEN tb.CashPayMethod = 10 THEN 'TotalPOSPrice'
        END) as name,
       SUM(tb.CashPayPrice) as value
FROM mytable tb
WHERE tb.CashStatus = 0 AND tb.CashPayMethod IN (0, 10)
GROUP BY tb.[CashPayMethod]
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple option here is to just take a union:

```
SELECT SUM(CashPayPrice) AS Value, 'TotalCashPrice' AS Name
FROM mytable
WHERE CashStatus = 0 AND CashPayMethod = 0
UNION ALL
SELECT SUM(CashPayPrice), 'TotalPOSPrice'
FROM mytable
WHERE CashStatus = 0 AND CashPayMethod = 10;
```

Another option would be to look into using SQL Server's `UNPIVOT` operator.  But that might be overkill if your actual problem isn't much bigger than this.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UNPIVOT` to achieve desired output:

```
declare @tmp table(TotalCashPrice int, TotalPOsPrice int) 

insert into @tmp values (41000000, 12000000)

select u.[Value], u.[Name]
from @tmp s 
unpivot 
( 
    [Value] 
    for [Name] in ([TotalCashPrice], [TotalPOsPrice]) 
) u
```

Result:

[image]

If the original column names (TotalCashPrice, TotalPOsPrice) can change in number you will need dynamic TSQL.